# Will it hurt my website's SEO friendliness if I host a french targetted website at, let's say, godaddy.com?

Tags: seo, web-development, website-design, web-hosting

I have read that the server location is important for a website to be SEO friendly. I am planning to build a website from scratch which is targetted mainly to french audience (in france), but I am planning to host the web site at godaddy.com.

My concern is will it hurt the website SEO friendliness? Or do you recommend me to host the website in france itself? I have also read that I need to have a static IP Address. If it's true, can anyone explain me for what reason?

Can anyone suggest me some good web hosting companies, prefereable in france?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Hosting country does affect in two ways:

1) Average load time  (in your case though, France to GoDaddy servers should not be too large)

2) SEO: If your competitor has similar site hosted in France (similar page rank etc), he is likely to be shown higher in google.fr results and you are likely to be shown higher in google.com results. Naturally you would much rather have the former. Note that this applies only when comparing two equivalent sites hosted in different countries - not too widely different or differently ranked sites.

I suggest get a server in France.

---

Don't use dynamic IP:

1. Average DNS resolution time (for queries  at the moment when your IP has just changed, the effective resolution time for some users *can* be as large as the TTL - ),
2. SEO (not confirmed, but I am sure Google doesn't like a new IP every time it crawls your website),
3. high likelihood of any mail sent from your domain with dynamic IP landing in spam,
4. maintenance overhead, lack of robustness etc.

---

Check out some VPS providers in France. http://www.lowendbox.com/tag/france/ Be sure you can manage your own VPS before getting one though.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use a .fr domain name, the location of the server shouldn't matter. You should never host any serious website on a dynamic IP address, for all kinds of reasons, but I sincerely doubt that GoDaddy has any hosting packages that don't have static IP addresses.